# Matrix multiplication associative?

Tags: linear-algebra

Say I have a matrix $X$ and a vector $y$.

Is $X^T y = y X^T$? If so is this the case if $y$ wasn't a vector and instead of a matrix? Having trouble realizing this. Sorry if it's a dumb question, any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Do you mean “commutative” instead of “associative”?

Comment: I assume $y$ is a column vector. The expression $y X^T$ doesn't make sense because the dimensions don't match up.

Comment: I think, Lily, if you try writing down any example, you'll see that your equation doesn't hold. **But** matrix multiplication *is* associative – your question has nothing to do with associativity.

Comment: Sorry, I meant commutative.

Comment: But yes I understand it doesn't make sense. Thank you guys!